# What happens to the reference variable after a Component is destroyed in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

New to ExtJS. I have the following code.

```
var comp;
console.log('comp is - ' + comp);
comp = Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
    listeners : {
        beforedestroy : function(comp) {
            console.log('beforedestroy .. ');
        },
        destroy : function(comp) {
            console.log('destroy .. ');
        }
    }
});
console.log('comp is - ' + comp);
console.log('comp id is - ' + comp.getId());
comp.destroy();
console.log('comp is - ' + comp);
console.log('comp id is - ' + comp.getId());
```

The console output from chrome is

```
comp is - undefined
comp is - [object Object]
comp id is - component-1009
beforedestroy .. 
destroy .. 
comp is - [object Object]
comp id is - component-1009
```

It looks like even after the component is destroyed, the variable is still holding a reference to the original component. I was expecting the variable to have a value of undefined or null after destroy. Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way that Ext-JS could nullify your reference to an existing component since JavaScript doesn't have C++ like references.

For example:

```
var a = {b:2};
var b = a;  
// a and b both reference `{b:2}`, there is nothing you can do 
// to `{b:2}` that would change a or b to be null
```

You can check that a component is destroyed using the undocumented `isDestroyed` property.

```
comp.isDestroyed // true
```

You'll also notice that the component is removed from the registry

```
Ext.getCmp(comp.id); // undefined
```

Comment: Depending on what holds references to what, it may also be necessary in some circumstances to null out the reference to allow it to be collected.

Comment: Does this mean the memory is not freed when the component is destroyed?

Comment: Some of the memory is freed; as the documentation states, event handlers are removed. It cannot be garbage collected until your program doesn't have any references to it. That's one of the many bad aspects of global variables. If it was local to a function, the reference doesn't exist after the function exits, so it will be garbage collected (unless you're referencing it in a closure).

Comment: The DOM elements that were rendered were also removed.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are seeing is in line with what the docs claim.

> Attempts to destroy any objects passed to it by removing all event
>   listeners, removing them from the DOM (if applicable) and calling
>   their destroy functions (if available). This method is primarily
>   intended for arguments of type Ext.Element and Ext.Component, but any
>   subclass of Ext.util.Observable can be passed in. Any number of
>   elements and/or components can be passed into this function in a
>   single call as separate arguments.

Source - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-destroy

If you look at the source code, it does not delete the actual component anywhere. i.e. the component will be *practically useless* after a call to destroy but that's not the same thing as that object being garbage collected.

Comment: Another way to say it, you cannot force garbage collection on an object. If there's still a reference to it, it will live on.